# OpenLayers2 how to get feature info on form submit?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wfs-t

I have an OpenLayers pop-up with a form on `selectFeature` (WFS-T). Can I recover the feature.attributes in the form's `onSubmit`?

e.g: the form in the popup

```
var content = '<form onSubmit="processForm(this.form)">' +
    'Träd-Id<br><input type="text" name="trädnummer" value="' +
    feature.attributes.trädnummer + '">' +
    '<br>Art<br><input type="text" name="art" value="' +
    feature.attributes.art + '">' +
    '<br>Anmärk.<br><textarea name="anmärkningar" rows="4" cols="40">' +
    feature.attributes.anmärkningar + '"</textarea>' +
    '<br>Åtgärd<br><textarea name="anmärkningar" rows="4" cols="40">' +
    feature.attributes.rekommendationer + '"</textarea>' +
    '<br><input type="submit" value="Spara""></form>'
```

and the `onSubmit` callback:

```
function processForm(oForm) {
  var feature = **recover currently selected feature here?**
  feature.attributes.trädnummer = 
    oForm.elements["trädnummer"],value;
  feature.attributes.art = 
    oForm.elements["art"],value;
  feature.attributes.anmärkningar = 
    oForm.elements["anmärkningar"],value;
  feature.attributes.rekommendationer = 
    oForm.elements["rekommendationer"],value;
  return false;
}
```

If so, I thought I could use WFS-T to update the attribute info? (instead of e.g. a post to PHP)
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought: you can add a hidden field in the form with `id` of your feature and then reach the feature itself (so attributes too) by this `id` (via `getElementById`) in `onSubmit` callback.

Comment: Thanks @unibasil - that's sorted it. I also got rid of the <form> and onSubmit stuff and used the WFS-T I'd already set up (feature.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE; saveStrategy.save(); in a button click handler). I'll post the updated code.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I added ids based in feature.id in the input fields and used getElementById to recover the inputs in the button click handler. I used this.wfs.selectedFeatures[0] to get to the attributes in the button click handler